# Set allowDiskUse:true in mongodb compass aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I am having trouble trying to call `{allowDiskUse:true}` in the mongodb compass GUI tool. I have created a view based on an aggregation of another collection. The view returns an error of

```
Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting.
```

Hence i saw that it is required to append `{allowDiskUse:true}` but i am unable to find a suitable place to call. There is a possibility to use the `$out stage` to write to another collection but I would like to try the view first :)

ADD ON:
I have tried to run the query `db.noDups.aggregate([],{allowDiskUse : true });` in command line and it works. But I would like to execute in MongoDB compass for the visualization and exporting function.

I also tried `{},{},{allowDiskUse: true}` in the filter condition but still no luck :(

Btw I am on MongoDB 4.2.6 Community and MongoDB compass 1.25.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can refer to this community thread -> https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/allowdiskuse-setting-in-compass/11851/4

Comment: hm so that is to create the view using console yea?

Comment: Yes, You can create a view in the console, and use find on the view you just created in the Compass with {allowDiskUse: true}.

Comment: I created in console and run the query with allowDiskUse set to true, and the query succeeded. But I would like the MongoDB compass to be able to display the view results too

Comment: In Compass, in the Filters in options , Try this out {},{},{allowDiskUse: true}

Comment: Hm still no luck though :( pls see attached screenshot above

Answer (score 2):

I tried appending it to the filter and it didn't work. I've looked on many different forums and kind find a solution for allowDiskUse from Compass.  This seems kind of crazy that you need to add such a kludgy option to even do modest groupings on small amounts of data.

I also have been looking to see how to increase the amount of memory that Mongo can use to get around having to do this.  I have Mongo installed on a server with 512GB of memory, it seems rather silly to have developers jumping through hoops like this.